# Getting a profiler error i CPLEX OPL -Overflow occured

Tags: cplex, opl

I am getting an error in CPLEX about profiler error.This is being shown in the Profiler tab at the bottom window.

Overflow occurred, please use oplrun -profile

I have my outputs written back to excel using the sheetwrite command ( like for example solXbimt to SheetWrite(sheet,"Result!B3:E1000000");  ). The engine log shows there are several solutions that have been generated but they do not get written back to excel. I am doubting the overflow is causing this.

Can you please help how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run your model with oplrun ?

If you do not need profiling you could also remove this.

You could also write your solutions in a .dat file

To save memory instead of running your model in the OPL IDE you may use command line oplrun.

And in the postprocess block you may save your solution into a file through IloOplOutputFile.

Example from https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplscripting/blob/main/zooandsaveresultindatfile.mod

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

execute
{
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("zooresult.dat");
  o.writeln("nbBus40=",nbBus40,";");
  o.writeln("nbBus30=",nbBus30,";");
  o.close();
}

/*
generates zooresult.dat
nbBus40=6;
nbBus30=2;
*/
```

Comment: Hi Alex Thank you so much for the response and extremely sorry for my delayed response. It took me some time to try it.  I had the lines to be written to .dat file as tuples, and it works wonderfully for tuples as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again Alex using your response I tried the following: For me each of the Sol variables below are tuples. Another thing noticeable is that now it runs much faster than it used to when I was writing back to excel. This is a great workaround for writing results to .dat files when your output size is large.

```
execute
{
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("optscheduleXbmt.dat");
  o.writeln(solXbmt);
  o.close();
  
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("optscheduleXbdt.dat");
  o.writeln(solXbdt);
  o.close();
  
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("optscheduleXbst.dat");
  o.writeln(solXbst);
  o.close();
  
  
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("optscheduleXsmt.dat");
  o.writeln(solXsmt);
  o.close();  
  
   
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("optschedulePath.dat");
  o.writeln(solPath);
  o.close(); 
}
```